# Translate text for empty product

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change the text of an empty product. But my code covers all products and I need this only for free products, meaning empty price products. Here is my code:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text');

add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) {
       if( empty($product->price) ){
              $translated = str_ireplace('Weiterlesen', 'Contact US', $translated);

              return $translated;
       }
}
```

This code is working perfectly, but it covers all products. I mean, the empty price condition is not working as expected here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function 'translate_text' variable **$product** is not initialized, so the price is always empty. You need to provide the $product for use inside the function, consider the function, it should be global. Try modifying function:

```
function translate_text($translated) {
  global $product;

  if ($product && empty($product->price)){
    $translated = str_ireplace('Weiterlesen', 'Contact US', $translated);
  }

  return $translated;
}
```

If your $product is set as global, this will work, if not, you need to set it like that, or think of another way to provide this function with outside variable.